# How to catch the event the mousePressEvent on Esri :: ArcGISRuntime :: Graphic?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, c++, events, qt, arcgis-runtime

All events mouse protected. I tried to do it via eventFilter and using QObject :: connect, but the result false. How do I catch a click event on Graphic?
What I tried:

```
...
    void ViewshedGeoElement::graphic3dMouseClicked()
    {
        qDebug()<<"m_graphic3d";
    }

    bool ViewshedGeoElement::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug()<<obj<<event;
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
        {
            graphic3dMouseClicked();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
...

Esri::ArcGISRuntime::Graphic* m_graphic3d = nullptr;
m_model3d = new ModelSceneSymbol(QUrl(dataPath + PathModel), 1.0f, this);
m_model3d->setAnchorPosition(SceneSymbolAnchorPosition::Bottom);
m_model3d->setHeading(180.0f);
m_graphic3d = new Graphic(dp.m_pos, m_model3d, this);

m_graphic3d->attributes()->insertAttribute(HEADING, dp.m_heading);
m_graphic3d->attributes()->insertAttribute(PITCH, dp.m_pitch);
m_graphic3d->attributes()->insertAttribute(ROLL, dp.m_roll);

m_sceneView->graphicsOverlays()->at(0)->graphics()->installEventFilter(m_graphic3d);
```

...

the second way doesn't work either:

```
...
void ViewshedGeoElement::graphic3dMouseClicked()
{
    qDebug()<<"m_graphic3d";
}
...
QObject::connect(m_graphic3d,SIGNAL(mousePressEvent()),this,SLOT(graphic3dMouseClicked()));
```

Answer (score 1):

My code selects one Graphic and highlights it:

```
...
    QObjectList m_PointLogLag;
...
void ViewshedGeoElement::connectSignals()
{
    // handle the identifyLayerCompleted signal
    QObject::connect(m_sceneView, &SceneQuickView::identifyGraphicsOverlayCompleted, this, [this](QUuid, IdentifyGraphicsOverlayResult* result)
    {
        if (result->graphicsOverlay()->graphics()->isEmpty())
            return;
        // get the results
        GraphicListModel* graphicElements = result->graphicsOverlay()->graphics();
        for(int i=0;i<graphicElements->size();i++)
        {
            Point loaction = graphicElements->at(i)->geometry();
            qDebug()<<floor(loaction.x()*10000 )/10000<<floor(m_PointLogLag.last()->property("latitude").toDouble()*10000 )/10000;
            qDebug()<<floor(loaction.y()*10000 )/10000<<floor(m_PointLogLag.last()->property("longitude").toDouble()*10000 )/10000;
            if (floor(loaction.x()*10000 )/10000==floor(m_PointLogLag.last()->property("latitude").toDouble()*10000 )/10000,
                floor(loaction.y()*10000 )/10000==floor(m_PointLogLag.last()->property("longitude").toDouble()*10000 )/10000)
            {
               graphicElements->at(i)->setSelected(true);
               return;
            }
        }
    });

    //     when the scene is clicked, identify the clicked feature and select it
    QObject::connect(m_sceneView, &SceneQuickView::mousePressed, this, [this](QMouseEvent& mouseEvent)
    {
        //     clear any previous selection
        m_sceneView->graphicsOverlays()->at(0)->clearSelection();

        Point clickedPoint = m_sceneView->screenToBaseSurface(mouseEvent.x(), mouseEvent.y());
        m_PointLogLag.append(new Coordinates(clickedPoint.x(),clickedPoint.y()));

        //     identify from the click
        m_sceneView->identifyGraphicsOverlay(m_sceneView->graphicsOverlays()->at(0), mouseEvent.x(), mouseEvent.y(), 10, false);
    });
}
...
```